# How to manipulate parameters like @path with ForFiles

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I'm using [forfiles](/questions/tagged/forfiles) in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to find all files changed within the last day and save them to an archive directory.

The script works perfectly to pull files from one directory to another, however it does not do the desired function when there are sub directories.

e.g. I have a Source location and an Archive directory. In the source directory there is the following structure:

```
C:\Temp\Source\test1.txt
C:\Temp\Source\Folder\test2.txt
```

The Archive directory is simply the below location with no files/sub folders in it:

```
C:\Temp\Archive
```

My current use of `ForFiles` picks up both `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` and dumps them into the `Archive` directory, which is an undesired result:

```
C:\Temp\Archive\test1.txt
C:\Temp\Archive\test2.txt
```

What I want to do is preserve the folder structure and get this result:

```
C:\Temp\Archive\test1.txt
C:\Temp\Archive\Folder\test2.txt
```

This is the code I'm currently using to achieve the undesired result is:

```
FORFILES /S /p %source_dir% /m *.* /d +%datedsub% /c "cmd /c copy @path %archive_dir%"
```

*`%datesub%` is just my variable to decide what date to copy from.*

I have noted that I could achieve this by using the `@relpath` parameter, removing the quotes and `.\`, then appending it to the `%archive_dir%` so that I'm specifying the entire destination path rather than just the `Archive` location.

My problem is that I do not know how to manipulate the `@` variables whilst within a `ForFiles` command.

Comment: You are using wrong commands Type `xcopy /?`.

Comment: ...or better still the command which superseded it, `RoboCopy /?`

Comment: There's a few reasons why I'm not using these commands (around how I'm manipulating the date field, UNC paths, etc). I'll be honest, I can't remember the exact reasons as I wrote the base script that contains inputs for the date, FTP functions,etc, a couple of years ago, but it started with Robocopy and I had to make a concession and go back to a simple copy to get it working.